# How to display different data types in radial stacked chart using D3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization, converters

I'm trying to display data in a radial chart/donut chart where there is a threshold and an overshoot. The data I am displaying is in percent, tonnes, kg per capita, scale(0-1). I'm guessing I would have to convert the data to a common type like percent, but I'm unsure how to go about it.

The chart is supposed to look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vpOwY.jpg)

Another [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VCcFM.jpg)

Here is a snippet of the data:

| Planetary Boundry | Threshold | Overshoot |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Climate Change | - 2.35 tonnes CO2 equivalent per capita yearly | 18.95 tonnes CO2 equivalent per capita (2020) |
| Ocean acidification | - 1.59 tonnes CO2 per capita yearly (until 2055) | 15.33 tonnes CO2 per capita (2020) |
| Nitrogen | 100% good or very good ecological condition (limit between moderate and good = 250-775 µg/L) | 72.7% |
| Biodiversity / land use | 0.6 (scale 0-1) | 0.45 |

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want, maybe you could give some examples? Meanwhile, the best way to convert stuff is using scales. You can use a scale for each type and convert to a common domain (like [0, 100])

Comment: Sorry if my questions wasn't clear. I'm not that familiar with charts, but I assume all datas would need a bottom value(Normally 0) and a top value to calculate how big the bars should be. I'm having trouble since my data is in different types. I also don't know what my bottom point is when some of the "threshold" values are negative numbers. I guess my question is; How do I convert the data to a common type? How do I calculate the size of the bar when dealing with negative numbers.

Comment: If you could make me an example of how you would convert one of the datas I presented to a 0-100 scale it would be really helpful for doing the rest by myself.

Comment: You can have one scale for each data type, but with a common range. When you render a specific section of the chart, you can use the relevant scale.

Comment: for example, climateChangeScale = d3.scaleLinear().domain(d3.extent(climateData)).range([0,100]) and oceanScale = d3.scaleLinear().domain(d3.extent(oceanData)).range([100,200])